# Community users not able to access lightning components in Napili template, while System Admins are able to access when logged in to Communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili

We created a lightning component with a button whose job is to insert a record in custom settings. Component is enabled to access globally and implements "forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes". 
Added this component to Napili community home page. System Administrators are able to see the button on community while others can't see anything.
Below is my component:

Comment: Can you post the code so that I can try in my org?

Comment: Can a community profile actually create custom settings? I would have thought you would need permission to access the setup menu

Answer (score 1):

You must give read permissions to the profile for the objects you use in your component.